# Dynamic ID URL issue

Tags: php, mysql

So I've been looking over the site for detailed information on dynamic urls I would like to implement them on my website, as I'm learning PHP I feel it's a good exercise. Here is my scenario.

I have a search engine already made, say I search for a monster called 'Skeleton'. There is a page created that will display results in a table and the first table cell contains a link to a page (in this example /monsters/?id=3). I have my monsters folder with an index.php file created with this code snipped (gathered from other questions and answers) and I wish to print content on my page:

```
<?php 
include ('../includes/functions.php');
$id = (isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : NULL);

if ($id) {
    $pContent = $DB->query_first("SELECT * FROM `monsters` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
        print_r($pContent);
    }
    ?

>
```

I have this set up, and the required fields set in my MySQL database, yet no results are being found. I am currently getting this error, although not entirely sure what it means (I actually haven't searched this yet as I was typing this then thought I may have an error, forgive me)

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function query_first() on a non-object in /xx/xxx/xxxxxxx/v1.2/monsters/index.php on line 6
```

Sorry for this newbie question, just trying to learn what I can. :)

Comment: the variable $DB is not initialized. check you functions.php

Comment: Ah of course. This is still pretty much applied to another question. In this case, is $DB essentially a mysql_query? Just trying to figure out what I need to add to my functions for $DB to work, or more accurately, what I need to change $DB to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance for the $DB object. Say for example the class for the DB object was Database you would do:

```
$DB = new Database('whatever paramaters you need');
if ($id) {
    $pContent = $DB->query_first("SELECT * FROM `monsters` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    print_r($pContent);
}
```

If the query_first function is not in a class and is just out in the open in the functions.php file you would call it like this instead:

```
if ($id) {
    $pContent = query_first("SELECT * FROM `monsters` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    print_r($pContent);
}
```

Comment: Ok, my Database is already created. What would be the function of $DB->query_first be? Why should I need it?

Comment: How are you instantiating the database?

Comment: I have a connection made included in my functions.php file if this is what you mean.

Comment: I updated my answer, I put in an example of what you would do if the query_first function is not inside a class, and is just out in the open in the functions.php file.

Comment: Ok great! I haven't defined query_first as anything yet, so that must be the issue. I got this code from another question and it really wasn't explained at all. What would I want to define query_first() as in functions.php in order for this script to work in the manner I want it to?

Comment: If you haven't defined query_first as a function yet, it's not going to work. I would advise using mysqli_query instead. Here's a link to the PHP docs for mysqli_query [php.net/mysqli_query](http://php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: Ok great, I will test this now.